# Compiler trying to load libraries used by an included shared library (C++ & cmake)

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I have a main program A and an included shared library libB.so. I made library B because the library it utilizes has conflicts when included at the same time as the library that program A utilizes. I would like to make sure that the compiler for program A will not try to include any libraries that library B uses.

However with my current setup, the compiler for program A complains that it can not find the library included by library B (Which in this case is library D). Any ideas on how to modify this code to keep library B's dependencies from also being loaded by program A?

**a.cpp:**

```
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"

//c.h is a library that does not work when library d (which is in b.h) is included

int main() {
    b object;
    object.print();
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.h"
#include "d.h"

//d.h is a library that does not work when library c (which is in a.h) is included

b::b() {}
void b::print() { std::cout << "Hello"; }
```

**b.h**

```
#include "d.h"
#include <iostream>

class b {
    public:
        b();
        void print();
};
```

**CMakeLists.txt for program A:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
PROJECT ( a )
list( APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} )
include( FindPkgConfig )

find_package( b REQUIRED )
find_package( c REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${B_INCLUDE_DIR} ${C_INCLUDE_DIR} )
target_link_libraries( a ${B_LIBRARY} ${C_LIBRARY} )
add_executable( a ${B_LIBRARY} ${C_LIBRARY} )
```

**CMakeLists.txt for program B:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
PROJECT ( b )
list( APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} )
include( FindPkgConfig )

find_package( d REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${D_INCLUDE_DIR} )
target_link_libraries( b ${D_LIBRARY} )
add_library( b SHARED ${D_LIBRARY} )
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say *"d.h doesn't work when c.h is included"*?

Comment: Please post any error messages you get *verbatim*, *in the question*.

Comment: do you ask about how to use `#ifndef`?

Comment: Compiler error or linker error?

Comment: There is a typedef conflict, between PocketSphinx and OpenCV. OpenCV has typedef long long int64 and Pocketsphinx uses typedef int64_t int64. I've removed it from the code I am using in the question because I want to know how to keep the two pieces of code from ever coming in contact through libraries.

Comment: Also the error is that when compiling program A, the compiler claims that it can not find "d.h"